# Deploying a Java servlet based application from local server onto Virtual server

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, web-deployment-project

As the question explains I want to deploy a Java servlet based application which is developed on a local server (Apache Tomcat 6.0). I have the IP address, Host name for the new virtual server. I want to know, if it will be just a normal site migration process where I'll have to install Tomcat on the new server and configure the server, web XML files or is there a bit more.
As I have not done Tomcat config before. Any Help would be great

- Is there a step-by-step documentation to perform this
  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Download and install Java
2. Download Tomcat http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi
3. Read http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/setup.html
4. Build your webapp into a war file with your build scripts
5. Copy the war file into webapps directory under your tomcat installation directory.  More details can be found http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/deployer-howto.html

I find it best to create a script that deploys my webapp from running my build script.  And scp and ssh task comes in handy for installing it quickly.  There are probably other maven tasks that might work for you.

Comment: Thanks chubbard. How do i create build script for webapp. I have the project/ application under webapps folder in the local server

Comment: You can use Ant or Maven to do that.  http://techtracer.com/2007/04/16/the-great-ant-tutorial-a-great-jump-start/ and maven tutorial http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html

Comment: Thanks Chubbard that really helped and I was able to do that. Dont understand why my question it was under-rated though..